# Way to implement features of (.altmacro) without using it

Tags: assembly, macros, clang, gnu, gnu-assembler

I am a beginner and I am presently using the %expr option available in .altmacro as given in https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html, but unfortunately my assembler doesnt support this. So I would like to know an alternate to do the same as % expr, i.e. evaluate the expression and use it as a string using gnu macros. Thanks in advance